# Menu won't change when hovered in submenu

Tags: css, hover, mouse

So basically i want to make my menu keep in hover state when their sub menu hovered,
i'd already try like this

but it still won't change as i want, where did i go wrong?
here's my snippet

```
#topmenu li li:hover a:hover{
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000; 
}
```

regards,

Comment: show your HTML structure as well please

Comment: show all of your menu CSS as there might be other styles overriding what you have.

Comment: <ul class="menu">
<li class="item-469 deeper parent">
<ul><li class="item-481"></li>
<li class="item-482"></li>
<li class="item-483"></li>
<li class="item-484"></li></ul></li>

Comment: here are complete css & html http://jsfiddle.net/FTHFQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're hiding your sub menu with `left: -999em;` rather than `display: none;`.

Here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JmkaM/1/ that uses `display: none;` and `display: block;` to show the sub menu.

What you want to do is display the sub menu when the user hovers a top level `li`.  So you would do that like this `li:hover ul`.  For your specifc CSS modify the following:

```css
#topmenu li ul {
     /* left: -999em; remove */
     display: none;  /* add */
}

/* add the following */
#topmenu li:hover ul {
     display: block;
}
```

If you really need to use `left` for some reason then do the following:

```css
#topmenu li:hover ul {
     left: 0;
}
```

It will bring your sub menu back from being pushed `-999em` to the left.  Though it might not be placed quite where you want it.

**UPDATE 1**

This will be the last time I help you.  You need to learn that good feedback will help others help you.  I understand that you are new but responding to answers with, "doesn't do what I want," does **not help us or you**.

I'm just guessing here at what you want based on the jsFiddle you linked to in the comments.

Here's the new jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JmkaM/2/

Below you will see the changes I made, before and after.  I only highlighted the properties that I changed for brevity.

**Before**

```css
#topmenu ul { /* ... */ }
#topmenu li ul {
     padding-top: 0px;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#topmenu li li:first-child {
     margin-top: 14px;
     border: 0;
}
```

**AFTER**

```css
/* added child selector '>' so only top level navigation
   items have a background of red */
#topmenu > ul { }
/* set padding on all sides to 0 */
#topmenu li ul {
     padding: 0;
}
/* removed whole rule - #topmenu li li:first-child */
```

**UPDATE 2**

Try this:

```css
#topmenu > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
#topmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: so in my code, where sub menu hovered the menu on top still have a white color background

Comment: My jsFiddle shows the sub menu.  The one that you linked to above does also.  What do you want your sub menu to look like when visible?  

You need to be more clear with people or they will stop trying to help you.  Simply stating, "doesn't work as I want," won't get you anywhere.  Give us some details please!

Comment: i mean, sub menu appeared just like that i wrote http://jsfiddle.net/FTHFQ/ but when i hovered in submenu (child class) the menu (parent class) is changing color as when its hovered (first red then white background)
im sorry for my english

Comment: So you want the parent menu item's background to not change when hovering the sub-menu?

Comment: yes it still in state when i hover the parent menu,
in my code, wehn i hover the submenu the parent menu background have red color, but i want to be white color(just like when it parent menu hovered)

Comment: thank you @hungerstar would you mind to explain what > used for?
especially in parent child list like this? it means a lot to me, Thx

Comment: It is the child selector, see here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector.  If you use `#topmenu ul` for a rule then *ANY* `ul` nested inside `#topmenu` will receive the style.  If you use `#topmenu > ul` only a `ul` that is a child of `#topmenu` will receive the style.  You can think of a child as the first level of elements inside another element.

Answer (score 0):

See this Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/mSNqT/46/

This will be helpful.

Comment: i tried like that with
`#topmenu a:hover li li a:hover{}`
but still dont work as i want

Comment: nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
try this